# Java items appear only after the window is resize

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have 2 JPanels in a frame. The first panel contains java items like buttons etc. The two buttons I added appears but the JSpinner appear just after I resize the window. I guess this will happen also with other items I will add. How could I solve this problem?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerListModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

public class StartingPoint {

static JFrame window;
static DrawingArea draw;
static JButton b1, b2;
static JPanel userInt;
static JSpinner gravitySpinner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    window = new JFrame("Ball");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(600, 400);
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    window.setVisible(true);

    draw = new DrawingArea();
    window.add(draw, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    userInt = new JPanel();
    window.add(userInt, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    b1 = new JButton("Start");
    b2 = new JButton("aaa");
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            draw.setUp();
        }
    });
    userInt.add(b1);
    userInt.add(b2);


    SpinnerNumberModel gravityModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(.9, .1, 2, .1);
    gravitySpinner = new JSpinner(gravityModel);
    userInt.add(gravitySpinner);
}
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're adding components to the GUI *after* calling `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame and that's backwards since you're rendering the GUI before anything has been added, and so it makes sense that things added later won't be displayed until all is repainted.

Instead, first add all your components, and only *then* render the GUI by calling `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame.

**Edit**
Also, you'll want to avoid calling `setSize(...)` on anything but instead let components size themselves using their preferredSizes and by calling `pack()` on the JFrame prior to displaying it with `setVisible(true)`.

**Edit 2**
For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StartingPoint {

   private DrawingArea draw;
   private JButton b1, b2;
   private JPanel userInt;
   private JSpinner gravitySpinner;

   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

   public StartingPoint() {
      mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      draw = new DrawingArea();
      mainPanel.add(draw, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      userInt = new JPanel();
      mainPanel.add(userInt, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      b1 = new JButton("Start");
      b2 = new JButton("aaa");
      b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            draw.setUp();
         }
      });
      userInt.add(b1);
      userInt.add(b2);

      SpinnerNumberModel gravityModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(.9, .1, 2, .1);
      gravitySpinner = new JSpinner(gravityModel);
      userInt.add(gravitySpinner);
   }

   public JPanel getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JFrame window = new JFrame("Ball");
            window.add(new StartingPoint().getMainPanel());
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            window.pack();
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }
}

class DrawingArea extends JPanel {

   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;

   public void setUp() {
      // TODO finish
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

}
```

Comment: And you want to wrap all your code in your main method in an `EventQueue.invokeLater()` call to respect the [Swing threading policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)

Comment: I should move all my code from main method in run method and in main mathod I have to add this    $SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new StartingPoint()); ?

Comment: @Alex: You would get rid of *everything* static in the code above, create your JPanel gui in the class itself, then in your main create a Runnable that initializes your class, adds the class's JPanel to a JFrame and then displays the JFrame. For example, see **Edit 2** above.

Comment: I made the changes like in edit2 but now it doesn't work Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError. Should I create a new thread or something? And Thank you again.

Comment: Do you mean a new thread here at StackOverflow? Yes, probably since this is a new problem. It smells though as if you're doing something recursively, like having a method call itself or calling a class's own constructor inside of itself.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702827/how-elements-in-container-adjust-when-we-resize-window

Answer (score 6):

Add `setVisible(true)` at the end and it works.