# How elements in Container adjust when we resize window?

Tags: java, swing, window, panel, frame

Below is the code for a Window which changes color when the user clicks a button, and changes the text of a label when he clicks the other button.

It has two buttons, a panel for holding buttons, a label, and a panel for graphics.

Conceptual explanation:
    First, I added the `label` to the `North` part of the `frame` using the default `BorderLayout`. Then I added the two `buttons` in a separate panel, and I added that `panel` to the `South` part of the main `frame`. Then I added the `panel` for the graphics in the `Center` of the main `frame`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
class GuiAnimation extends JFrame
{

JButton colorBut;
JButton labelBut;
JLabel label;
PaintCanvas firstCanvas;
JPanel buttonPanel;

GuiAnimation()
{

    colorBut = new JButton("Color Change");
    labelBut = new JButton("Text Change");
    label = new JLabel("I will change");
    firstCanvas = new PaintCanvas();
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    addListener(); //May be i should make different method for different component for the flexibility.But here program is small.
    addEverything();
}

private void addListener()
{

    colorBut.addActionListener(new ColorListener());
    labelBut.addActionListener(new LabelListener());
}

private void setButtonInPanel()
{
    int pad = 80;
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, pad, 20));
    buttonPanel.add(colorBut);
    buttonPanel.add(labelBut);
}
void addEverything()    //Here things are done with Layouts.
{
    //add the label to the top of the window.
    this.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, label);
    //add button inside the panel.  
    setButtonInPanel();
    //add that panel that has button to the frame.
    this.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonPanel);
    //add the graphics canvas to the frame.
    this.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, firstCanvas);
}

class PaintCanvas extends JPanel
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);

        Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

        g.setColor(randomColor);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

}

class ColorListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        firstCanvas.repaint();
    }
}

class LabelListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        if ( label.getText().equals("I will change"))
            label.setText("yes yes yes clicked");
        else 
            label.setText("I will change");
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    GuiAnimation gui = new GuiAnimation();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(500,600);
    gui.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Here is the output of above code.So far so good.

[image]

But when I start to slide from the right-hand side, the following happens:

[image]

Now the right wall of the window is coming towards the left, but the buttons are stationary. Continuing this we get:

[image]

However, if we resize from the left side, we get:

[image]

Here the button seems to move towards the right, along with the frame (maintaining its distance from the frame boundary). This is the opposite of the previous case. But Why? How?

Finally, we have:

[image]

Continuing this, the "ColorChange" button also becomes partially invisible.

Why are these two different things happening, if we slide from right to left versus left to right?

I have searched, but I was unable to find an accurate answer to this, so finally I  am asking here: Why and How?

Comment: Don't generate random colors in the paintComponent() method. The background will change every time the frame is resized. Based on the buttons added to the frame it should only change when you click on the "Color Change" button. So when you click on the button you should generated the random Color and invoke the setBackground(...) method with the color. The panel will then repaint itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have explained the problem, but you haven't explained the requirement.

Maybe you should consider a [Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

```
panel.add( Box.createHorizontalGlue() );
panel.add( button1 );
panel.add( Box.createHorizontalStrut(20) );
panel.add( button2 );
panel.add( Box.createHorizontalGlue() );
```

This will create a panel where the buttons remain centered with a gap of 20 pixels between the two buttons.

Comment: As you were saying that after "TextChange" button there is a gap and when we slide from right to left the gap decreases but There is a gap before "ColorChange" button and why it is not decreasing when we slide from left to right?In other words why 80px is maintained in case of "ColorChange" button and in the other case it is not?

Comment: i want some suggestion from your side. If i practice only GridBagLayout will it be sufficient to code any type of GUI (nearly any type), with the basic knowledge of other LayoutManagers?

Comment: @Rouftantical, I use whatever layout manager (or combination of layout managers) is right for the job.

Comment: Do i need indepth knowledge of all of them to be a good designer?

Answer (score 2):

It's because of your gap-value at

```
int pad = 80;
buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, pad, 20));
```

. It's always 80px. So the first button is **always** 80px away from the "beginning" of the panel. If you slide from right to left, nothing changes, except one button dissapears because there's not enough space to fill 3 gaps. However, if you slide from left to right, The first button **doesn't** vanish firstly because as mentioned before, it **has** to have a gap of 80px from the beginning. Sorry for my miserable english, but I hope I have helped.

Comment: but if i don't give it any padding both from left and right one of the button is visible when i completly slide to the other end . But why not both?

Comment: (1+), this is the correct answer. The `FlowLayout` will automatically move components to a new row when there is not enough space for a component to be displayed on the first row. If you want the "wrapped" buttons to also be visible then you can use the [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) which extends `FlowLayout` to handle this behaviour. You just need to change one line of code: `buttonPanel.setLayout(new WrapLayout(WrapLayout.LEADING, pad, 20));
`

Comment: @LuxxMiner what are 3 gaps your are talking about?

Comment: Your original statement is correct, there are 3 gaps when the panel is displayed at its `preferred size`: 80 pixels before the "Color Change" button. 80 pixels after the "Color Change" button and 80 pixels after the "Text Change" button. As the frame shrinks the gap after the "Text Change" button will decrease until the gap completely disappears and the "Text Change" button wraps to the next row.

Comment: @camickr As you were saying that after "TextChange" button there is a gap and when we slide from right to left the gap decreases but There is a gap before "ColorChange" button and why it is not decreasing when we slide from left to right?In other words why 80px is maintained in case of "ColorChange" button and in the other case it is not?

Comment: @Rouftantical That is the way the FlowLayout was designed to work because you are using LEFT alignment. If you use RIGHT alignment the gap will change on the left. If you use CENTER alignment the gap will change on both sides. But the gap is initially the same before/after each component. I suggested a different layout manager which works differently and allows you to use different gaps.

Comment: @camickr oh means the space on right hand side matters for placement in a new row?

Comment: @Rouftantical, Yes, it is just like a text editor. If a word can't fit on a row it wraps to the next row.

Answer (score 1):

This could possibly what you need: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html

I haven't worked on Swing/JavaFX in a while, but I do believe that you can give frame.pack(); a shot.